# How can I create multiple log files based on multiple data Input files with log4j config file in Java

Tags: java, log4j

I have one requirement like, if there are 10 files(which is dynamic) to transform then for all these 10 files, log file should be generated separately(10 logs files if there are 10 input files).
I tried implementing it by using Marker feature of log4j however since the marker is static and it will hold the values at class loading itself. I am not able to pass file names dynamically and it is still taking first file and generating single file and writing logs for remaining files in that file itself.